# Nx 16 Invalid package name "@nx-cloud"

Tags: angular, npm, npx, nrwl-nx, nx.dev

I'm getting the error ***Invalid package name "@nx-cloud" of package "@nx-cloud@16.0.5": name can only contain URL-friendly characters.*** everytime I try to install any package to my project. Is there any problem with the last version of Nx or maybe i have a wrong configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The package should be nx-cloud and not @nx-cloud